# AngularJS Convert String to Object/Array that references the objects in the $scope

Tags: javascript, string, angularjs, implicit-conversion

I created a directive in angular where its scope is not isolated

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <ul>
      <li myDirective="model[1].list" >a lot more things will happen inside here</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
app.controller("myController",["$scope",function($scope){ 
$scope.model = [
       {
          list:[ "object1","object2","object3" ]
       },
       {
          list:[ "object4","object5","object6" ]
       },
       {
          list:[ "object7","object8","object9" ]
       }
    ]
}]);
```

Directive:

```
    app.directive("myDirective",[function(){
    return {
         scope:true,
         controller:function($scope,$element,$attrs){
             /*
              How do I directly be able to manipulate from inside here what is assigned 

on the  $attrs.myDirective 

without ISOLATING the scope of the directive

                  */
             }
        }

    }]);
```

one of the solution i used was this function i put this inside the directive and process the string assigned to the $attrs.myDirective it works well with "model.list" 
but with "model[2].list" it doesnt because its not built for it. How do I modify this function or are there better solutions for this problem...

```
    $scope.rediks = function(string)
    {          
        var scope = $scope; 
        var scopeSplit = string.split('.');
        for (i = 0; i < scopeSplit.length - 1; i++)
        {
            scope = scope[scopeSplit[i]];
            if (scope == undefined) return;
        }
        return scope[scopeSplit[scopeSplit.length - 1]];
    }
```

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `$parse` service ([docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse)) to get the value pointed to by the attribute:

```
controller: function($scope,$element,$attrs,$parse) {
    var value = $parse($attrs.myDirective)($scope);
    // for the above case, value = [ "object4","object5","object6" ]
}
```